# Error when launching cpp-coveralls

Tags: python, c++, coveralls

When I launch the cpp-coveralls utility to send my code coverage result to http://coveralls.io, I always get this error:

```
$ coveralls 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/coveralls", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: requests
```

I tried with two python version (2.7.2 and 3.3.3) but I always have the same result...
I get this error both local and on the travis build for my test project:

- https://github.com/MartinDelille/TravisTest/tree/gcov
- https://travis-ci.org/MartinDelille/TravisTest/builds/20284896

I post an issue here: https://github.com/eddyxu/cpp-coveralls/issues/27 but I wonder if it doesn't come from my configuration...

Comment: It seems coveralls is missing the `requests` module. How do you manage your dependencies? You seem to be using the OS X framework Python, therefore you'd need to install `requests` in a way that this Python finds it, e.g. `sudo easy_install requests`. A better way would be to set up a [`virtualenv`](http://www.virtualenv.org) though.

Comment: thanks for the PR! I'll check right away :-)

Comment: I hope it solves the issue - hard to tell without actually running the travis build myself :)

Comment: In progress: https://travis-ci.org/MartinDelille/TravisTest/builds/20350178

Comment: Looks like it didn't solve the issue. Strange, I watched as it installed the `requests` module. I'll clone your repo and see if I can debug the issue locally.

Comment: I tried it locally with `pyenv` installed via `brew`, after running the followings commands `pyenv install 2.7.2 && pyenv local 2.7.2` and it worked...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49308/discussion-between-martin-delille-and-lukas-graf)